# Symfony access_control Rule

Tags: symfony, access-control

I have 3 user roles

> 1. ROLE_STAFF
> 2. ROLE_ADMIN
> 3. ROLE_CUSTOMER

I want to implement following rule for my admin dashboard.

1. Allow user with role `ROLE_ADMIN` all access
2. Do not allow access to user with role `ROLE_CUSTOMER` to any url starting with `/admin`
3. Allow not logged in user to access url starting with `/account`
4. Allow user with role ROLE_STAFF to access url starting with `/admin/business/*`

For the above rule, I have implemented following rule in access_control

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/account, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/business, role: ROLE_STAFF }
    - { path: ^/admin/dashboard, role: ROLE_STAFF }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This is not working as expected, the problem is, when I am logged in with ROLE_STAFF it works but when I login with ROLE_ADMIN it throws access denied error.

What could be possible issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: You know that the first rule wins. Try moving `{ path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }` to second line and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know your `role_hierarchy ` so you might as well check the config here. The stricter the role, the higher it is placed: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/07wr/in-memory-style-user-authentication-and-authorisation-with-webform-login-box